# Select with where clause that uses a field that is not in index returns: Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query is not supported

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table with a composite primary key:

```
class tablea {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
    * @ORM\id
    */
    protected $a;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\id
    */
    protected $b;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    */
    protected $c;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $d;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $e;
}
```

When I try to execute a query to return all record with d=100 (for instance) I allways get a error message:

> Binding an entity with a composite primary key to a query is not
>   supported. You should split the parameter into the explicit fields and
>   bind them separately.

here is my code:

```
    $_qry = $_rep->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->Where("m.d = :ini")
            ->setParameter('ini', 100)
            ->getQuery();
```

But, if I change to a field that is an index or if I remove the where clause, the query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix your exact error, but you may want to look into the [limitations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#primitive-types-only) Doctrine has with composite keys, specifically the restriction on only having primitive types - in your example you're using a `datetime` as an ID. It could be that this is causing the problem.

While not a solution, this is one of those instances where trying to make Doctrine play nice is going to be more hassle than either:

- just adding a synthetic generated key to the entity
- using native SQL / a different ORM solution (e.g. Propel)

The impact of either of these choices is obviously dependent on your project - I've found the former the easiest way to go about things, however if you're porting an existing project or you expect the table to be massive (or you're just really picky over normalisation) then this may not be the way to go.

In short: composite keys in Doctrine are a short path to pain.